# Compiled HTML (.Chm) Building from project

Tags: html, chm, manual

I've been searching lately for different way to present a user manual that is easy to use and understand.

At first, I tought that the Microsoft Help files would be great, since I knew my way around basic HTML. Little did I knew that Microsoft Help Workshop was a bit more complicated than simply taking HTML and processing it. I had multiple problem while trying to ajust the different styles and classes applied to my HTML.

What would be the best tool to use to convert an existing HTML project (HTML, CSS and basic Javascript) to a compiled .CHM file?

If it is not possible, what option would be worth exploring when making maintainable user manuals?

Thanks.

Comment: Really belongs on the Software Recommendation SO site, http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would explore using [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert your html or markdown to docbook or pdf, or any of 100s of other formats.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Have you ever used it on HTML ?

Edit : My concern would be the transition of the different style format.

Comment: I have used it on html - but be aware that any complex formats and javascript renderings spring to mind are unlikely to cross well between formats, (short of open in a web browser and print to pdf and I have seen problems even with that).

Answer (score 0):

There are various tools available to do that. Few noteworthy are: [nDoc](http://www.helpndoc.com/) or [DocBook](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/) or [FAR HTML](http://www.helpwaregroup.com/products/far) or [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) or Microsoft's [SandCastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/)